# How to copy information from 1 .PST file to another

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, file-transfer, pst

I have been using an Outlook Data file for a long time now and have *many* calendar events, tasks, notes, and contacts. I recently got an exchange account set up and would like to know if there is a way to copy all of the information from my current .pst file to the exchange and make that my default instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, certainly. Go to `File>Open>Import`

[image]

It should default to "Import from another program or file", Go down to "Outlook Data File" and hit Next. Browse to your PST, and hit Next.

It will ask you where you want to import it to, and you will click "Import items into the same folder in:" and then pull down your Exchange mailbox in the drop-down box, and click "Finish".

[image]

Comment: What if I am trying to copy from a .PST to a .OST? Is this possible?

Comment: The OST is just a cached copy of the Exchange mailbox. Just import it into Exchange, and you will, in effect, import it into an OST.

Comment: I also am adding a little more specific end to my answer since I did not have a PST to test with...just created one.